# How to set the address from which manifest.json is fetched from on Azure

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, web-config, azure-web-app-service, manifest.json

I've hosted two web apps on the same azure app service using virtual applications. One is located in site/wwwroot and the second one is in site/wwwroot/management.

The second application is an ASP .Net Core app that hosts static JS files. I've confirmed that the app is running, but when I try to navigate to the url, the website tries to fetch the static files from the root of the application, while they're located in the /management sub folder. I've confirmed this by successfully requesting manifest.json from https://foobar/management/manifest.json

I've tried to change the start_url property in the manifest.json, but I guess that's not where the problem is since the website doesn't know where to fetch in the first place. Maybe there's a way to specify the location of the manifest.json in the web.config, but I couldn't find anything about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is configured by the "homepage" property in package.json

`"homepage": "https://foobar/management"`